# Exception when attempting to create Namespaced Pod

Tags: kubernetes

The KubernetesPodOperator in my Airflow dag is trying to launch a pod using the following pod spec (replaced some config values with `xxx`):

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Pod",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {
      "sidecar.istio.io/inject": "false",
      "azureDisk": {
        "kind": "Managed",
        "diskName": "airflow-buffer",
        "diskURI": "xxx",
        "cachingMode": "None"
      }
    },
    "labels": {
      "airflow_version": "1.10.15",
      "kubernetes_pod_operator": "True",
      "dag_id": "cxf-main",
      "task_id": "cxf-main",
      "execution_date": "2021-11-20T0300000000-d97e9064f",
      "try_number": "3"
    },
    "name": "xxx",
    "namespace": "airflow"
  },
  "spec": {
    "affinity": {},
    "containers": [
      {
        "args": [],
        "command": [
          "python",
          "src/main.py"
        ],
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "name": "xxx",
            "value": "production"
          }
        ],
        "envFrom": [],
        "image": "xxx",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
        "name": "base",
        "resources": {
          "limits": {},
          "requests": {}
        },
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "mountPath": "/mnt/buffer",
            "name": "xxx",
            "readOnly": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hostNetwork": false,
    "imagePullSecrets": [
      {
        "name": "xxx"
      }
    ],
    "initContainers": [],
    "nodeSelector": {},
    "restartPolicy": "Never",
    "securityContext": {},
    "serviceAccountName": "default",
    "tolerations": [],
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "persistentVolumeClaim": {
          "claimName": "xxx"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, the Kubernetes API is returning an exception and I can't figure out why:

```
Pod in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Pod: v1.Pod.ObjectMeta:
v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects \" or n, but found {, 
error found in #10 byte of ...|reDisk\": {\"kind\": \"M|..., bigger context ...|\"sidecar.istio.io/inject\": \"false\", \"azureDisk\": {\"kind\": \"Managed\", \"diskName\": \"airflow-buffer\", \"|...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested annotations and thats also what the error is telling you.

```
v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects \" or n, but found {,
```

You are not allowed to do this.

```json
"annotations": {
      "sidecar.istio.io/inject": "false",
      // cannot nest azureDisk inside annotations
      "azureDisk": {
        "kind": "Managed",
        "diskName": "airflow-buffer",
        "diskURI": "xxx",
        "cachingMode": "None"
      }
}
```

This object belongs in the volumes array.

```json
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "mydisk",
        "azureDisk": {
          "kind": "Managed",
          "diskName": "airflow-buffer",
          "diskURI": "xxx",
          "cachingMode": "None"
        }
    }
]
```

You can also see this in this documentation for example, in YAML format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv